# Crash CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData: vm_copy failed: status 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, crash, cgbitmapcontextcreate

I am facing a crash with following error:

> "CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData: vm_copy failed: status 1."

I have multiple questions and you can help.

1. What does status 1 stand for in vm_copy failed?
2. This crash happens only when I set a break point in the inner for loop of data copy. And then resume and remove the breakpoint. If there is no breakpoint, function executes but I get a blank image. How do I ensure that even if I don't set a break point, such crashes are caught and application stops execution?
3. This error comes when I execute CGBitmapContextCreateImage. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
-(UIImage *) convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:(UInt8**)img 
                                    :(int) width
                                    :(int) height 
{

CGImageRef inImage = m_inFace.img.CGImage;

UInt8*piData = calloc( width*height*4,sizeof(UInt8));

int iStep,jStep;
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) 
{
    iStep = i*width*4;
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) 
    {
        jStep = j*4;
        piData[iStep+jStep] =img[i][j];
        piData[iStep+jStep+1] =img[i][j];
        piData[iStep+jStep+2] = img[i][j];

    }
}

CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(piData,
                                         CGImageGetWidth(inImage),  
                                         CGImageGetHeight(inImage),  
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(inImage),
                                         CGImageGetBytesPerRow(inImage),  
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(inImage),  
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(inImage) 
                                         ); 

CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);  
UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
free(piData);
return finalImage;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [kern_return.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/osfmk/mach/kern_return.h) header file gives:

```
#define KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS        1
  /* Specified address is not currently valid.
   */
```

This corresponds to the error code related to `vm_copy failed: status 1`.

I suspect this is a problem related to memory alignment, since the [vm_copy documentation](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/vm_copy.html) states that *address[es] must be on a page boundary*.

To make sure you work with properly aligned buffers, you should allocate your `piData` buffer with the same stride than your `inImage` input image:

```
size_t bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(inImage);
UInt8*piData = calloc(bytesPerRow*height,sizeof(UInt8));
```

Then use this `bytesPerRow` value instead of `width*4` within your `for` loop, i.e:

```
iStep = i*bytesPerRow;
```

This should solve your problem (Note: I assume that `CGImageGetWidth(inImage)` and `width` are the same).

Comment: Yes it was memory alignment issue. I was not considering image orientation. Which gave different width and height for CGimage. That caused memory mis alignment as you pointed out. Thanks for the reply.